# Rails 3 CRUD shallow nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm trying to use [this example](http://stjhimy.com/posts/7) but it doesn't work.
I guess it's because I use a shallow nested model !
I get this error : Template is missing

```
Missing template pprojects/create with {:formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:builder, :erb, :haml, :rjs, :rhtml, :rxml], :locale=>[:en, :en]}

It looks like my app is trying to do HTML and no JS because my server console says the following:

Processing by ProjectController#create as HTML
```

Maybe I have a problem here :

```
<%= form_for([@organization, @project], :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

or because in my controller my load method isn't compatible with create and update :

```
def load
    @projects = Project.all
    @project = Project.new
  end

def create
    @project = @organization.projects.new(params[:project])
    if @project.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created project."
      @projects = Project.all
    end
  end

  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated project."
      @projects = Project.all
    end
```

Do you have a clue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i'm willing to bet you have your javascript_include_tags the wrong way round

try putting them like this:

```
// include jquery before you include rails.js file - it's very important!!
javascript_include_tag 'path/to/jquery'
javascript_include_tag 'path/to/rails'
```

It worked for me.